# Configuring Jest + Enzyme to run tests in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, jestjs, enzyme

I'm following the [TypeScript create-react-app tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter) and I managed to get Jest + enzyme working through the command line, but I'd also like to be able to test single functions and whatnot inside of PhpStorm. However I keep getting the following error when running through PhpStorm:

> Error: An error occurred while adding the reporter at path "/snap/phpstorm/36/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-reporter.js".Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

What should my test setup/configuration look like? I can't seem to find any examples in the PhpStorm Docs or otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: How does your run/debug configuration look like? Please attach a screenshot.